# How do I make multiple concurrent VOIP calls from one PC?

Tags: sip, libraries, voip

I'm trying to create a program that can manage devices in the field by phoning them and sending various DTMF tones.  An important requirement is that I can have multiple calls happening in parallel, simultaneously playing different tones.

I am currently using sflphone on Linux, and have a program that can make a useful call.  However I can't find a way of making a second call in parallel -- the first call gets put on hold.

Does anyone know of any libraries, software, hacks etc to make this happen?

Comment: In the end I went with abdul's suggestion of the Ozeki library.  It seemed well designed and worked quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PJSUA softphone, it is open-source and allows multiple calls: http://www.pjsip.org/

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently using is called a softphone (software telephone). You can't run parallel instances of it since it requires access to the sound devices in your computer (speakers and microphone).
You need to write some kind of VoIP client which is not a softphone. There are many libraries for it, resiprocate to name one if you are using c++.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Ozaki library to achieve our VOIP telephony purposes. It has he proper components allowing you to [manage simultaneous VoIP calls](http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_542-how-to-handle-more-than-one-call-in-the-same-time-voip.html).